# How to query a Table Storage in Azure Storage Explorer with Synapse Azure?

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-synapse

I know how to query a regular file (csv, parquet, json, etc). However, I would like to know how to perform a query directly on a Table Storage. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share some details on the types of queries you would like to run directly against Tables?

Comment: Hi @GeethaThatipatri-MSFT! I would like something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset#data-source). But I don't know if it's possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation link you have shared, seems like you are trying to query Azure Table Storage data from Synapse Serverless Pool.

If that's the case, then it is not supported to query Azure Table Storage from Synapse Serverless SQL Pool. Please refer to this feature request regarding the same in Azure IDEAS forum: [Serverless Pool and External Table/ CETAS support for Azure Storage Tables and Queues](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e8b84b27-0b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)